# Demographic data Age/Gender not showing in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have already integrated Google SDK in my IOS app and try to track everything that happening in the app.I am successfully getting active users record, Ecommerce stats except Demographic data. I have already 'Enable Demographics and Interest Reports' in the ADMIN settings and integrated the code in the application. I have enabled it a long ago But no success. I don't know what i am doing wrong

These are the lines which i implemented in the code:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

I checked the **kGAILogLevelVerbose** logs also and it shows me all the logs with the IDFA . Please guide me if anybody knows what settings i am missing.